# Is there a way to keep the *Messages* buffer scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: scrolling, message

I like to watch the `*Messages*` buffer while I debug elisp code.  However, I often have to manually scroll the buffer as it fills up to see new messages.  Is there any way to keep the `*Messages*` buffer constantly scrolled down to the last line of content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the cursor/point at the end of the `*Messages*` buffer (e.g. using `M->`).
If you keep it there, the message buffer will stay 'scrolled down'.

Comment: That worked.  I didn't know you could do that and that it was *sticky*.  [end-of-buffer](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Buffer-End-Motion#command-end-of-buffer-optional-n)